# Weak convergence can imply strong convergence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, limits-and-convergence

In $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$, weak convergence implies strong convergence. Is there a classification of infinite-dimensional Banach spaces for which such a property holds true ?

Comment: If you are only asking about convergence of sequences, then perhaps Schur's property is what you are after? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_property

Comment: To be more precise, the spaces where weak convergence implies strong convergence are precisely the finitnie-dimensinonal ones. For $\ell_1$ the key point is that we consider only sequences, not more general nets.

Comment: (just to clarify: Jochen and Willie's comment address the same duplicate)

Comment: Rosenthal's $\ell_!$ theorem implies that a space has the Schur property if and only if every bounded non totally bounded sequence has a subsequence that is equivalent to the unit vector basis of $\ell_1$.